# rabl-rails gem, passing locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I'm looking for a way to pass locals when using the rabl-rails gem
The syntax from the "normal" rabl gem doesn't work:

```
extends('posts/show', :locals => { :hide_comments => true })
```

Extends in rabl-rails seems to accept only one argument.
Does anybody know how to do this?